# UITabBar text is not properly align with icons in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

With a UITabBar, I'm having a problems with text alignment when I'm in landscape mode.  What's the best way to center the text up and down so its aligned with the center of the image?

- I do understand that the text will be on the right in landscape mode, I'm looking to center it with the icon.
- My images are custom images but I have made 1x, 2x, and 3x versions at 25x25, 50x50, and 75x75.
- I have the TabBar's bottom constraint set to Superview.Bottom.

I can fix it, if I adjust every tab bar item when I'm only in landscape mode with the following code, but this seems wrong.  Also not sure if this would hold up on all devices.

```
surveyTabBar.items![1].titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset.init(horizontal: 0, vertical: -10)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found was to adjust with the UIOffset, but I only adjust in landscape mode.

```
@IBOutlet var myTabBar: UITabBar!

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    adjustTabBarTitles()
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    self.adjustTabBarTitles()
}

private func adjustTabBarTitles() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        for item in self.myTabBar.items! as [UITabBarItem] {
            item.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -8)
        }
    } else {
        for item in self.myTabBar.items! as [UITabBarItem] {
            item.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working, I tried it